# Every sample of $25$ from a set of $30$ marbles contains at least $3$ white, at least $5$ blue, and at least $7$ black marbles

Tags: combinatorics

Here's a problem I came across:

> In a bag, there are $30$ one-color marbles of three different colors,
>   say black, blue, and white. If we randomly take $25$ marbles out of the
>   bag, among our picks will always be at least three white, at least
>   five blue, and at least seven black marbles. How many marbles of each
>   color are there in the bag originally?

From my interpretation of the wording, every sample of $25$ will have at least $3$ white, $5$ blue, and at least $7$ black. What's the most concise way to answer the question with my interpretation of the situation?

Answer (score 2):

There are $30$ total marbles. You pick out $25$, leaving $5$ in the bag. Now consider the worst case scenarios:

- If the $5$ marbles left in the bag are all white, then you need that initially there were $8$ white marbles in order to guarantee that at least you will have $3$ marbles in your draw that are white.
- If the $5$ marbles left in the bag are all blue, then initially you would need $10$ blue marbles in total to guarantee at least $5$ blue in your draw.
- If the $5$ marbles left in the bag are all black, then you need that initially there were $12$ white marbles to guarantee at least $7$ black in the draw.

Adding up: $8$ (white) + $10$ (blue) +$12$ (black) =$30$ marbles.

This will guarantee you the result.

Answer (score 1):

Even if all $5$ unsampled marbles are white, we still have $3$ white marbles in the sample, so there must be $3+5=8$ white marbles.  Similarly, there are $10$ blue and $12$ black.  Note that the colors changed in the middle of the problem; I'm using the second set.